# Get all markers under paticular cluster

Tags: mapbox, markerclusterer, mapbox-gl-js

Is there a way to get an array of all markers under the cluster icon on cluster click.
I am using standart mapbox gl cluster https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/cluster/
Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/2661#issuecomment-294569012

Comment: @stdob-- Thanks!